# Detect "Windows" key of qwerty keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-hardware, hardware-interface, qwerty

In my current code, I am attaching the qwerty keyboard and detecting the key events in android code.
Now, the issue is that, I cannot able to detect the "Windows" (some says "Search") key. Whenever I press "Windows" key at that time no log found in dispatchKeyEvent. How can I able to detect it?